# Magento admin redirecting in loop

Tags: magento-1.7, redirect, admin-panel

Magento Admin url keep on redirecting and shows the below error.
**This webpage has a redirect loop**

Frontend is working fine, but the problem is with the magento admin url.

Also this problem occurs after implementing patch.

Comment: share the patch number.

Comment: Below Patches were manually implemented by my frnd prabhu..
SUPEE 1533,
SUPEE 5344,
SUPEE 6482....

htaccess file not changed. But not sure this is due to patch

Comment: check admin store url in core config table and also check any thing present in htaccess file

Comment: Ok. But htaccess file not changed. I will check admin store url

Comment: You should add more info, like what configurations do you have, when did the problem start? is it production or local etc.

Comment: Its production site. I dont know whether my client changed any configuration.

Comment: Thanks Guys @MeenakshiSundaramR , FROSIT for support. I found the issue. It occurs after enabling ssl. I have fixed it by adding this line in htaccess------- SetEnv HTTPS "on"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the cause for the issue.
It is due to enabling of SSL.

Use the below code in **.htaccess for Apache server**.

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    SSLOptions StdEnvVars
    SetEnv HTTPS "on"
</IfModule>
```

Using nginx with php-fpm add these lines to **nginx.conf**:

```
fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
```

Answer (score 1):

I had problem with 302 loop, spent lots time to find source, nothing found, had remove memcached, varnish, forced apache to work alone on bitnami gcloud, so l=place here related answer:

In problem to open admin pannel of magento 2, and in apache logs you see infinite redirects:

*.76.240.181 - - [29/Oct/2017:14:52:03 +0000] "GET /admin/admin/index/index/key/1efd57644c83b7dddeafcbfa2ae317722fdf09a44a529cbd6c59ae612cce5f8d/ HTTP/1.1" 302 -
*.76.240.* - - [29/Oct/2017:14:52:03 +0000] "GET /admin/admin/index/index/key/2e928a54097b04300bce0396dfefd14f0f6d00f8685facd90396c2a1748e2c31/ HTTP/1.1" 302 -
*.76.240.* - - [29/Oct/2017:14:52:03 +0000] "GET /admin/admin/index/index/key/7f171df1bebc545167632253133055efcb0cf22be8d0d2f25da876da7157b842/ HTTP/1.1" 302 -
*.76.240.* - - [29/Oct/2017:14:52:04 +0000] "GET /admin/admin/index/index/key/0cefdc9644a14e247523f7e022d874db0e8dda2ab60f61ae337c5f6ab2ac267a/ HTTP/1.1" 302 -

delete all cookies for doamin, sure helps

Answer (score 1):

If you have recently enabled HTTPS

```
magento config:set web/secure/use_in_adminhtml 1
```

I found this command several pages deep into google and it fixed the admin HTTPS redirect error.