# Magento Admin page redirect

Tags: magento2, admin, redirect

I have deployed Magento machine on Centos7 Machine. When I try to login to the admin page, it tries to redirect to the same page. i have already tried clearing the cookies. But that has not helped. SSL is enabled on the machine. Based on this [question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/84247/magento-admin-redirecting-in-loop), it is because SSL is enabled, I have tried the fix mentioned as well.

Not all users face the issue. Now the admin page doesn't popup as it says there were too many redirects from this page.

Unless the cookies are cleared no user is able to get the admin page without redirect.

Answer (score 0):

- Try changing admin URL path in **app/etc/env.php**. If it does not solve your problem, go to next step.
- If you are working on the local server and have setup website's URL like http://localhost/foldername/, then change it to http://127.0.0.1/foldername/. If still, the problem persists, check the next step.
- Go to your database and look in the table **core_config_data**. You should see a path called **web/cookie/cookie_domain**. Make sure the domain matches the one you installed Magento 2 on. Ex: If you installed Magento 2 on **local.dev/** the entry in **web/cookie/cookie_domain** should be local.dev.

**One more thing:** **Don't use _ (underscore) in your store's URL.** Magento 2 Admin can't handle the use of an underscore _ in the URL.

**Note:** After checking any step, you need to remove /var/cache folder.

Please let me know if it solved your problem. Also, share if you were able to solve your problem by some other way.

Comment: 1. The file env.php, do not contain any admin url path other than the front_name for the admin url
2. This is not set up in a local machine.
3. Cookie_donain is set to NULL